# How to Disable 'Preferences' Button in Print Dialog in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am looking for a way to disable 'Preferences' Button in Print Dialog in WPF. What I want is preventing the user from clicking that button and do unnecessary changes to the print.

I want to do it without creating a whole other print dialog on my own. Is there a possible way of accessing those buttons from code behind and manipulate them?

Comment: i dont think there is anyway you can hijak/change the browser printer dialog windows

Comment: You can use winapi to [disable control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enablewindow) (see [pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/EnableWindow.html)) if you get its handle. I am not sure how to get handle for that dialog button, I guess you need to find it by enumerating (see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3774738/1997232)).